# Can't enter numbers using numbers pad

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation, format

I have a function that formats user input into phone format.

It works fine except it's not allowing numbers from numbers pad at the right, Only the numbers at the top of the alphabetic characters.

I want to keep the same format, But allow entering numbers from numbers pad.

Here is a fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/s1wyrmk6

Here is the code:

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="phone">
```

JS/jQuery:

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.usPhoneFormat = function (options) {
        var params = $.extend({
            format: 'xxx-xxx-xxxx',
            international: false,

        }, options);

        if (params.format === 'xxx-xxx-xxxx') {
            $(this).bind('paste', function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var inputValue = e.originalEvent.clipboardData.getData('Text');
                if (!$.isNumeric(inputValue)) {
                    return false;
                } else {
                    inputValue = String(inputValue.replace(/(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})/, "$1-$2-$3"));
                    $(this).val(inputValue);
                    $(this).val('');
                    inputValue = inputValue.substring(0, 12);
                    $(this).val(inputValue);
                }
            });
            $(this).on('keydown touchend', function (e) {
                if (e.which != 8 && e.which != 0 && (e.which < 48 || e.which > 57)) {
                    return false;
                }
                var curchr = this.value.length;
                var curval = $(this).val();
                if (curchr == 3 && e.which != 8 && e.which != 0) {
                    $(this).val(curval + "-");
                } else if (curchr == 7 && e.which != 8 && e.which != 0) {
                    $(this).val(curval + "-");
                }
                $(this).attr('maxlength', '12');
            });

        } else if (params.format === '(xxx) xxx-xxxx') {
            $(this).on('keydown touchend', function (e) {
                if (e.which != 8 && e.which != 0 && (e.which < 48 || e.which > 57)) {
                    return false;
                }
                var curchr = this.value.length;
                var curval = $(this).val();
                if (curchr == 3 && e.which != 8 && e.which != 0) {
                    $(this).val('(' + curval + ')' + " ");
                } else if (curchr == 9 && e.which != 8 && e.which != 0) {
                    $(this).val(curval + "-");
                }
                $(this).attr('maxlength', '14');
            });
            $(this).bind('paste', function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var inputValue = e.originalEvent.clipboardData.getData('Text');
                if (!$.isNumeric(inputValue)) {
                    return false;
                } else {
                    inputValue = String(inputValue.replace(/(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})/, "($1) $2-$3"));
                    $(this).val(inputValue);
                    $(this).val('');
                    inputValue = inputValue.substring(0, 14);
                    $(this).val(inputValue);
                }
            });

        }
    }
}(jQuery));
```

Comment: Use `console.log(e.which)` to see what the code is for number keys.

Comment: Numpad #1 is `which` of `97` for me

Comment: @Barmar, It returns from 48 to 57 for numbers at the top

Comment: You're question isn't about the numbers at the top.  It's about the numberpad.

Comment: And from 96 to 105 for numbers on the numbers pad

Comment: Ok, so if the which is `96`, what does your logic do?

Comment: @Taplar, I provided it for both in case the code checks for the numbers at the top only

Comment: @Taplar, I want to allow entering numbers from the numbers pad and keep the same phone format, Now it's only allowing numbers from the top of the keyboard

Comment: Right... I'm telling you to step through your logic.  If the value is 96, what does it do?

Comment: This part needs to be extended `if (e.which != 8 && e.which != 0 && (e.which < 48 || e.which > 57)) {
                    return false;
                }` , But how to exclude the range from 96 to 105?

Comment: If you are logically trying to exclude anything that is not a number it would be (pseudocode) `if (!range1 && !range2)`, no?

Comment: Right, But how to edit the condition to allow both from 48 to 57 and 96 to 105 only?

Comment: `!( ( 48 <= e.which && e.which <= 57 ) || ( ... ) )`

Comment: You might want to check out this page, which discusses how to convert keyboard events into characters in detail. https://unixpapa.com/js/key.html

Answer (score 0):

Change the following

```
if (e.which != 8 && e.which != 0 && (e.which < 48 || e.which > 57)) { return false; }
```

The additional range 96 to 105 is greater than 57 currently, which causes this statement to catch the numpad.

To allow the numpad:

```
if (e.which != 8 && e.which != 0 && (e.which < 48 || (e.which > 57 && !(e.which>=96  && e.which<=105 )))) { 
    return false; 
}
```